# Python (Tkinter) Click button to make text appear in entry box?

Tags: python, button, tkinter

I am trying to make text appear in an entry box in my GUI application when a button is pressed. The aim is that when one button is pressed some defined text appear int he textbook and when another button is pressed the previous entry box is cleared and different text is inserted into the same entry box.

I am new to Python and therefore unsure how to do this? So far I have got three buttons to display different text each buttony in the GUI as text rather than text in separate text boxes. Could someone help please? Here's my code currently:

`# ***** Foreword Code *****

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter.messagebox

def new():
 tkinter.messagebox.showinfo('Window Title', 'Well, this is new...')

root = Tk()
root.title("GUI Test Version 2")
root.resizable(False, False)
root.geometry('{}x{}'.format(400, 400))
```

## ***** Main Menu *****

```
menu = Menu(root)
root.config(menu=menu)

subMenu = Menu(menu)
menu.add_cascade(label="File", menu=subMenu)
subMenu.add_command(label="New Experiment...", command=new)
subMenu.add_command(label="New...", command=new)
subMenu.add_separator()
subMenu.add_command(label="Exit", command=root.destroy)

editMenu = Menu(menu)
menu.add_cascade(label="Edit", menu=editMenu)
editMenu.add_command(label="Redo", command=new)
```

## ***** Toolbar *****

```
toolbar = Frame(root, bg="light blue")
toolbar.pack(side=TOP, fill=X)
```

## ***** Creating Buttons *****

```
class App(object):
     def __init__(self,root):
     self.root = root

     self.txt_frm = Frame(self.root, width=900, height=900)
     self.txt_frm.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
     button1 = Button(self.txt_frm,text="HELLO", command = self.hello_world)
     button1.grid(column=0,row=2, padx=2, pady=2)
     button2 = Button(self.txt_frm,text="GOODBYE", command = self.goodbye_world)
     button2.grid(column=1,row=2, padx=2, pady=2)
     button3 = Button(self.txt_frm,text="NEW", command = self.new_world, bg="red",fg="white")
     button3.grid(column=2,row=2, padx=2, pady=2)

 def hello_world(self):
        label = Label(self.txt_frm,text='HELLO WORLD!')
        label.grid(column=0,row=3)

 def goodbye_world(self):
        label = Label(self.txt_frm,text='GOODBYE WORLD!')
        label.grid(column=1,row=3)

 def new_world(self):
        label = Label(self.txt_frm,text='THIS IS A NEW WORLD!')
        label.grid(column=2,row=3)
```

## ***** Status Bar *****

```
status = Label(root, text="Preparing to begin...", bd=1, relief=SUNKEN,     anchor=W) # bd = bordered, relief = ,  appear placed in screen, anchor = w (NESW) needs two other properties
status.pack(side=BOTTOM, fill=X)
```

## ***** Run Code *****

```
app = App(root)
root.mainloop()`
```

Comment: Please don't intersperse your code with those useless headers. What most people  prefer is a single block of code that we can copy and paste. Also, please try to reduce the code down to a [mcve]. If the problem is with a button and an entry widget, we really only need one button and one entry widget to see what you're doing (plus enough code to make it run).

Comment: Instead of making headings please provide a single code. Also fix indentation

Comment: Your code has a lot of unrelated details like menus and labels and no entry boxes.

Answer (score 0):

The usual way to read and write to an Entry is to use a StringVar as textvariable. Inspect the code below:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.geometry('300x100')

class App(object):
     def __init__(self,root):
         self.root = root
         self.txt_frm = Frame(self.root, width=900, height=900, bg='khaki')
         self.txt_frm.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
         button1 = Button(self.txt_frm,text="Hello", command = self.hello_world)
         button1.grid(column=0,row=2, padx=2, pady=2)
         button2 = Button(self.txt_frm,text="Goodbye", command = self.goodbye_world)
         button2.grid(column=1,row=2, padx=2, pady=2)
         self.entry_var = StringVar()
         entry = Entry(self.txt_frm, textvariable=self.entry_var)
         entry.grid(column=0, row=3, columnspan=2, padx=2, pady=2)

     def hello_world(self):
            self.entry_var.set('Hello')

     def goodbye_world(self):
            self.entry_var.set('World')

app = App(root)
root.mainloop()
```

I'm assigning the StringVar `self.entry_var` to the entry. Then I use the button callback functions to alter the contents of the entry by modifying the `self.entry_var`.

Answer (score 0):

Make a label in `__init__` and use `label.config(text=text)` to change its text later. Here is an example code:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter.messagebox

def new():
 tkinter.messagebox.showinfo('Window Title', 'Well, this is new...')

root = Tk()
root.title("GUI Test Version 2")
root.resizable(False, False)
root.geometry('{}x{}'.format(400, 400))
menu = Menu(root)
root.config(menu=menu)

subMenu = Menu(menu)
menu.add_cascade(label="File", menu=subMenu)
subMenu.add_command(label="New Experiment...", command=new)
subMenu.add_command(label="New...", command=new)
subMenu.add_separator()
subMenu.add_command(label="Exit", command=root.destroy)

editMenu = Menu(menu)
menu.add_cascade(label="Edit", menu=editMenu)
editMenu.add_command(label="Redo", command=new)
toolbar = Frame(root, bg="light blue")
toolbar.pack(side=TOP, fill=X)
class App(object):
    def __init__(self,root):
        self.root = root

        self.txt_frm = Frame(self.root, width=900, height=900)
        self.txt_frm.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
        button1 = Button(self.txt_frm,text="HELLO", command = self.hello_world)
        button1.grid(column=0,row=2, padx=2, pady=2)
        button2 = Button(self.txt_frm,text="GOODBYE", command = self.goodbye_world)
        button2.grid(column=1,row=2, padx=2, pady=2)
        button3 = Button(self.txt_frm,text="NEW", command = self.new_world, bg="red",fg="white")
        button3.grid(column=2,row=2, padx=2, pady=2)
        self.label = Label(self.txt_frm,text='')
        self.label.grid(column=0,row=3)
    def hello_world(self):
        self.label.config(text="HELLO WORLD!")

    def goodbye_world(self):
        self.label.config(text="GOODBYE WORLD!")

    def new_world(self):
        self.label.config(text="THIS IS A NEW WORLD!")
status = Label(root, text="Preparing to begin...", bd=1, relief=SUNKEN,     anchor=W) # bd = bordered, relief = ,  appear placed in screen, anchor = w (NESW) needs two other properties
status.pack(side=BOTTOM, fill=X)
app = App(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: This is really helpful and answered my question.  I am also unsure how I can save the contents of these entry. boxes to a text file using the save dialog box you would normally get in a text editor application for example? Could you help with this please?

Comment: At the moment the code for saving is: def save_file():
    savefile = open ("newfile.txt", "w")
    savefile.write("Entry Box 1: " + entry_box1.get())
    savefile.write("\nEntry Box 2: " + entry_box2.get())
    savefile.write("\nEntry Box 3: " + entry_box3.get())
    savefile.close ()

Comment: However this does no-show the save dialog box and also. when I rerun the code, the old file is overwritten, I need to be able to specify a file name for each file and have them save separately with the text from the Entry boxes. How can I do this?

Comment: @HenryPowell-Davies, I don't see any entry in your code. Can you let me know which entry are you talking about? However, if you want to get the text of the label then use `self.label["text"]`, and it will return you the text as string